# Resizing the Root and Home directory

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I had partitioned Ubuntu during installation as; Root 70GB and Home 50GB. Now Root has free space of 60GB and Home is Full.
I would like to free some space say 20GB from Root and allocate it to Home. So finally expecting be like, Root with 50GB and Home with 70GB.

Note: It is a dual boot system with Windows 10 and Ubuntu
[image]

Since i am new to linux, i want to know,

1. Is it allowed to resize the Root and Home as i mentioned above
2. Will it have any harmful effect
3. If it is allowed, please tell me on how to do it

Thanks

Comment: If you can install gparted manager please install it and take screen shot of your partitions and paste it here this can help me to ask your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed move and resize partitions. Whether you can preserve existing data depends on the current situation.

**Reverting to just a / partition**

If you are new with linux, I would recommend you to stick to the default, i.e., having a single system partition containing your `/home` folder. That could be very fast: you just delete the /home partition, and then expand the root partition to fill all the space (in the assumption that your `/` is to the left of your `/home`).

- You will need to copy `/home` first to a removable medium that is formatted with a linux file system (`ext4`) such that file attributes and permissions are preserved in the copy. When done, copy the contents of that `home` back to the `/home` on the system partition
- While the system will startup when the `/home` partition is gone, you still would need to remove the line that contains `/home` in your system file `/etc/fstab`: that line causes the system to attempt mounting a partition that does not anymore exist.

**Resizing the partitions**

Alternatively, you could indeed decrease the size of the root partition (might be relatively slow because some data may need to be moved), then move the `/home` partition over to the left (will certainly be slow) and finally enlarge the `/home` partition (fast).

**How to repartition**

To repartition, you need to start up a live session (Installation DVD or USB), where you can load `gparted` for the partitioning. You apply changes in the graphical interface, then press the "Apply" button to carry out the change. I recommend here to proceed stepwise, i.e., do one change, hit apply and only continue if all goes well. Eventually, an error may pop up when you do the next step, and that them sometimes can be eliminated by shutting down and starting up another live session to continue.

Whatever you do, make sure you have a current backup of your user data on a removable medium anytime. If it is not you making a mistake, it is the hardware that can fail.